# Custom Annotation, Custom Callout with Buttons, with actions

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

This is my first time dealing with annotations and callouts.  I've got it working for the most part ( albeit, maybe not the correct way )

So, I have my mapView:

```
@interface MapViewController : BaseUIViewController 

<MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *friendsAnnotations;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *friendsResults;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *reloadTimer;

- (IBAction)zoomButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *zoomButton;
@end
```

The timer, I have set to reload the map every minute while you are on that screen.  It calls these functions:

```
#pragma mark - Update Map Annotations

- (void) getFriendsForAnnotations {
    [User syncUserWithCompletionHandler:^{
        [ServerComm listCollection:UsersCollection withValues:[DEFAULTS objectForKey:userActiveFriendsKey] forKey:mongoIDKey withCompletionHandler:^(NSDictionary *response) {
            [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.friendsAnnotations];
            [self.friendsAnnotations removeAllObjects];
            self.friendsResults = [[response objectForKey:@"results"] mutableCopy];

            dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
            for (id userDic in self.friendsResults) {
                User *theUser = [User userFromDictionary:userDic];

                dispatch_group_enter(group);
                if ([[userDic objectForKey:userPrivacyLevelKey] integerValue] == 0 ||
                    [[userDic objectForKey:userPrivacyLevelKey] integerValue] == 1
                    ){
                    NSDictionary *locationDic = [userDic objectForKey: userLastLocationKey];
                    BOOL checkedIn = FALSE;
                    if(![theUser.checkedInLocationName isEqualToString:EMPTYSTRING]) {

                        checkedIn = TRUE;
                    }
                    CustomAnnotation *CA = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:[userDic objectForKey:userUsernameKey] Location:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[locationDic objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue], [[locationDic objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]) UserImage:[userDic objectForKey:userProfilePictureURLKey] isCheckedIn:checkedIn];

                    [CA setCalloutUser:theUser];
                    [self.friendsAnnotations addObject: CA];
                }

                dispatch_group_leave(group);
            }
            dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self plotAnnotationsOnMap:self.friendsAnnotations];
            });
        }];
    }];
}

- (void) plotAnnotationsOnMap: (NSArray *) arrayOfLocations {
    [self.mapView addAnnotations: self.friendsAnnotations];
}
```

The point to this, is to setup the initial annotation for use with the standard `initWithAnnotation` method.

The final step to plotting our annotations on the map is the `viewForAnnotation` method:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotation class]]) {
        CustomAnnotation *myAnnotation = ((CustomAnnotation *)annotation);
        CustomAnnotation *annotationView = (CustomAnnotation *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"customAnnotation"];
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] initWithAnnotation:myAnnotation.annotation reuseIdentifier:@"customAnnotation"];
        }

        [annotationView setAnnotation:annotation];
        [annotationView.userImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myAnnotation.userImageString]];
        [annotationView setUserImageString:myAnnotation.userImageString];
        [annotationView setCalloutUser:myAnnotation.calloutUser];
        if (myAnnotation.isCheckedIn) {

            annotationView.markerImage.image = [annotationView.markerImage.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
            [annotationView.markerImage setTintColor:COLOR_BLUE_MUTED];
        } else {
            annotationView.markerImage.image = [annotationView.markerImage.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
            [annotationView.markerImage setTintColor:COLOR_GREY_LIGHT];
        }
        annotationView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, -39);
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;

        return annotationView;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

[image: Here, we have what my annotations look like at the end of this series of steps.]

This annotation is defined with a CustomAnnotation.h/m file as you would normally expect, and is pulled in from a xib.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "CustomAnnotationCallout.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface CustomAnnotation : MKAnnotationView <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UIView* loadedView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) User *calloutUser;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *calloutView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *markerImage;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *userImage;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *userImageString;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isCheckedIn;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL showCustomCallout;
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGRect endFrame;
- (id) initWithTitle:(NSString *)newTitle Location:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location UserImage:(NSString *)userImageString isCheckedIn:(BOOL)checkedIn;
- (void) setShowCustomCallout:(BOOL)showCustomCallout;
- (void) setShowCustomCallout:(BOOL)showCustomCallout animated:(BOOL)animated;

@end
```

and the .m file:

```
#import "CustomAnnotation.h"
#import "CustomAnnotationCallout.h"
#import "Utilities.h"
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
@implementation CustomAnnotation
- (id) initWithTitle:(NSString *)newTitle Location:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location UserImage:(NSString *)userImageString isCheckedIn:(BOOL)checkedIn{
    self = [super init];
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AnnotationView" owner:self options:nil];
    if (self) {

        if (_loadedView) {
            _loadedView.frame = CGRectMake(_loadedView.frame.origin.x, _loadedView.frame.origin.y, 80, 80);
            [self addSubview:_loadedView];
            self.userImageString = userImageString;
        }
        self.userImageString = userImageString;
        _title = newTitle;
        _coordinate = location;
        self.isCheckedIn = checkedIn;
        self.enabled = YES;
        self.canShowCallout = NO;
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_clear"];
        self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, 80, 80);
        self.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString*)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AnnotationView" owner:self options:nil];
        if (_loadedView){

            _loadedView.frame = CGRectMake(_loadedView.frame.origin.x, _loadedView.frame.origin.y, 80, 80);
            [self addSubview:_loadedView];
        }
        self.enabled = YES;
        self.canShowCallout = NO;
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_clear"];
        self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, 80, 80);
        self.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) setShowCustomCallout:(BOOL)showCustomCallout {
    [self setShowCustomCallout:showCustomCallout animated:NO];
}

- (void) setShowCustomCallout:(BOOL)showCustomCallout animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (_showCustomCallout == showCustomCallout) return;
    _showCustomCallout = showCustomCallout;
    void (^animationBlock)(void) = nil;
    void(^completionBlock)(BOOL finished) = nil;
    if (_showCustomCallout) {
        self.calloutView.alpha = 0.0f;
        animationBlock = ^ {
            self.calloutView.alpha = 1.0f;
            [self addSubview:self.calloutView];
        };
    } else {
        animationBlock = ^{ self.calloutView.alpha = 0.0f; };
        completionBlock = ^(BOOL finished) { [self.calloutView removeFromSuperview]; };
    }

    if (animated) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:animationBlock completion:completionBlock];

    } else {
        animationBlock();
        completionBlock(YES);
    }
}

@end
```

Now, if we click on the annotation we get our custom callout:

MapViewController Code:

```
- (void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:CustomAnnotation.class]) {
        CustomAnnotation *annotationView = (CustomAnnotation *)view;
        CustomAnnotationCallout *callout = [CustomAnnotationCallout new];
        callout.userImageString = annotationView.userImageString;
        [callout.userImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:callout.userImageString]];
        [callout.nameLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ @%@", annotationView.calloutUser.name, annotationView.calloutUser.username]];
        [callout setUserID:annotationView.calloutUser.userID];

        annotationView.calloutView = callout.loadedView;
        annotationView.calloutView.center = CGPointMake(annotationView.bounds.size.width*0.5f, -annotationView.calloutView.bounds.size.height*0.5f);
        [annotationView setShowCustomCallout:YES animated:YES];
        CGRect annotationViewWithCalloutViewFrame = annotationView.frame;
        annotationViewWithCalloutViewFrame.size.width += annotationView.calloutView.frame.size.width;
        annotationViewWithCalloutViewFrame.size.height += annotationView.calloutView.frame.size.height;

        CGRect mapRect = [self.mapView convertRegion:self.mapView.region toRectToView:self.mapView];
        mapRect.origin.y = annotationView.frame.origin.y-annotationView.calloutView.frame.size.height;
        mapRect.origin.x = annotationView.frame.origin.x+annotationView.calloutView.frame.origin.x;

        MKCoordinateRegion finalRegion = [self.mapView convertRect:mapRect toRegionFromView:self.mapView];
        [self.mapView setRegion:finalRegion animated:YES];

        [self.mapView setScrollEnabled:NO];
        [self.mapView setZoomEnabled:NO];
        [self.reloadTimer invalidate];
    }
}
```

CustomAnnotationCallout is also pulled in from a xib.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomAnnotationCallout : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *loadedView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *userImage;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString *userImageString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *userID;

- (IBAction)profilePressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)button2:(id)sender;

@end
```

and the .m:

```
#import "CustomAnnotationCallout.h"
@implementation CustomAnnotationCallout

- (instancetype)init {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomAnnotationCallout" owner:self options:nil];
    _loadedView.frame = CGRectMake(_loadedView.frame.origin.x, _loadedView.frame.origin.y, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 178.0);
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)profilePressed:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)button2:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

Now, when we select the annotation our custom callout changes and the map repositions itself to where I selected.  And we get this view:

[image: Selected Annotation to show Custom Callout]

Now that you see that what I have does work, and what i'm going for.  The problem that I'm having, is figuring out how to get the button(s) on the callout to perform a specific task when clicked.

I've googled and read about hitTest, but couldn't figure out anything specifically on how to implement it properly especially when looking to get it to work on specific elements.

I've been at this from start to finish this entire week and this is where I'm stuck.  Please note I've been doing iOS development for a total of about 4 months so I'm still relatively new.

Comment: Right now, when those buttons are tapped, do their actions get called?  If yes, then your question is just how to process that action in the view controller.

Comment: At the time of this posting, when tapped the actions did not get called.  I fixed this issue, and i'll give an answer as to how shortly...  Only problem I have currently, is on the didSelectAnnotationView and didDeselectAnnotationView methods.  If I select an annotation it pops up and works fine.  If I then select a different annotation, deselect is called, then select is called, then deselect is called again...  Been racking my brain on that one for a minute...